# favicon.ico displaying in edge even though not in the folder

Tags: html, microsoft-edge, favicon, ico

I use a favicon.ico file in a html project and now for every new html project which i open in edge, the favicon file shows up but not in any other browser even though it is not in the folder.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EphS.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ3rf.png)

I tried deleting the favicon file, clearing cookies and data of sites, turning off extensions, clearing cache. I asked chat-gpt and google it, but nothing resolves the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.